# How can ignore password filed in database if request password empty?

Tags: laravel

My password field is re-hashed, even when it's empty..

Code of controller :

```
   $request_data = $request->except(['password','_token','_method','avatar']);

   if($request->has('password')){

        $request_data['password'] = Hash::make($request->input('password'));
   }

   Admin::where('id' , $id)->update($request_data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `$request->has('password')` with `$request->filled('password')`

`$request->has('password')` will return true even if 'password' has no value whereas `$request->filled('password')` will return true only when 'password' has some value.

You can also use `$request->get('password')` or `$request->input('password')`

For more detail you can look https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests